# Reproject ImageCollection to ESRI:54009

Tags: coordinate-system, google-earth-engine, export, proba-v

I want to export PROBA-V's spectral bands to a specific coordinate reference system (ESRI:54009). So far, I am reprojecting each band separately before the export. I was wondering if there is a way to reproject the whole `ee.ImageCollection` one time instead of reprojecting each spectral band (i.e., 4*reprojections). I have tried to do something like this:

```
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('VITO/PROBAV/C1/S1_TOC_100M')
                  .filter(ee.Filter.date('2018-01-01', '2018-12-31'))
                  .select(['RED', 'NIR', 'SWIR', 'BLUE']);

// Project the image to Mollweide.
var wkt = ' \
  PROJCS["World_Mollweide", \
    GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984", \
      DATUM["WGS_1984", \
        SPHEROID["WGS_1984",6378137,298.257223563]], \
      PRIMEM["Greenwich",0], \
      UNIT["Degree",0.017453292519943295]], \
    PROJECTION["Mollweide"], \
    PARAMETER["False_Easting",0], \
    PARAMETER["False_Northing",0], \
    PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",0], \
    UNIT["Meter",1], \
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","54009"]]';

var proj_mollweide = ee.Projection(wkt);
var image_mollweide = dataset.reproject({
  crs: proj_mollweide,
  scale: 100
});

var median1 = image_mollweide.select('RED').reduce(ee.Reducer.median()).clip(table).divide(2000);

var median2 = image_mollweide.select('NIR').reduce(ee.Reducer.median()).clip(table).divide(2000);

Export.image.toDrive({
  image: median1,
  description: 'red',
  scale: 100,
  region: table,
  maxPixels: 1000000000000,
  folder: 'Landsat-5'
});

Export.image.toDrive({
  image: median2,
  description: 'nir',
  scale: 100,
  region: table,
  maxPixels: 1000000000000,
  folder: 'Landsat-5'
});
```

but it shows an error: `Line 21: dataset.reproject is not a function`.

This is what I am doing so far:

```
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('VITO/PROBAV/C1/S1_TOC_100M')
                  .filter(ee.Filter.date('2018-01-01', '2018-12-31'))
                  .select(['RED', 'NIR', 'SWIR', 'BLUE']);
                  
var median1 = dataset.select('RED').reduce(ee.Reducer.median()).clip(table).divide(2000);

// Project the image to Mollweide.
var wkt = ' \
  PROJCS["World_Mollweide", \
    GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984", \
      DATUM["WGS_1984", \
        SPHEROID["WGS_1984",6378137,298.257223563]], \
      PRIMEM["Greenwich",0], \
      UNIT["Degree",0.017453292519943295]], \
    PROJECTION["Mollweide"], \
    PARAMETER["False_Easting",0], \
    PARAMETER["False_Northing",0], \
    PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",0], \
    UNIT["Meter",1], \
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","54009"]]';

var proj_mollweide = ee.Projection(wkt);
var image_mollweide1 = median1.reproject({
  crs: proj_mollweide,
  scale: 100
});
                  
var median2 = dataset.select('NIR').reduce(ee.Reducer.median()).clip(table).divide(2000);

// Project the image to Mollweide.
var wkt = ' \
  PROJCS["World_Mollweide", \
    GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984", \
      DATUM["WGS_1984", \
        SPHEROID["WGS_1984",6378137,298.257223563]], \
      PRIMEM["Greenwich",0], \
      UNIT["Degree",0.017453292519943295]], \
    PROJECTION["Mollweide"], \
    PARAMETER["False_Easting",0], \
    PARAMETER["False_Northing",0], \
    PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",0], \
    UNIT["Meter",1], \
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","54009"]]';

var proj_mollweide = ee.Projection(wkt);
var image_mollweide2 = median2.reproject({
  crs: proj_mollweide,
  scale: 100
});

Export.image.toDrive({
  image: image_mollweide1,
  description: 'red',
  scale: 100,
  region: table,
  maxPixels: 1000000000000,
  folder: 'Landsat-5'
});

Export.image.toDrive({
  image: image_mollweide2,
  description: 'nir',
  scale: 100,
  region: table,
  maxPixels: 1000000000000,
  folder: 'Landsat-5'
});
```

How can I reproject the whole `ImageCollection` once so I won't have to do it for every spectral band? [Here](https://code.earthengine.google.com/5ecfe19a158942a49b1eec606928630b) is the link to GEE code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your OP it seems like you want to export a median composite, so it might be easier to first compute that composite and in the end just reproject it.

```
// Project the image to Mollweide.
var wkt = ' \
  PROJCS["World_Mollweide", \
    GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984", \
      DATUM["WGS_1984", \
        SPHEROID["WGS_1984",6378137,298.257223563]], \
      PRIMEM["Greenwich",0], \
      UNIT["Degree",0.017453292519943295]], \
    PROJECTION["Mollweide"], \
    PARAMETER["False_Easting",0], \
    PARAMETER["False_Northing",0], \
    PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",0], \
    UNIT["Meter",1], \
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","54009"]]';

var proj_mollweide = ee.Projection(wkt);

var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('VITO/PROBAV/C1/S1_TOC_100M')
                  .filter(ee.Filter.date('2018-01-01', '2018-12-31'))
                  .select(['RED', 'NIR', 'SWIR', 'BLUE'])
                  .median()
                  .divide(2000)
                  .reproject({
                    crs: proj_mollweide,
                    scale: 100
                  });

Export.image.toDrive({
  image: dataset ,
  description: '4BMedian',
  scale: 100,
  region: table,
  maxPixels: 1e12,
  folder: 'Landsat-5'
});
```

Answer (score 1):

@Jonathan V. Solórzano using your code I managed to export the bands as a raster stack, which is not what I asked for. Instead, I wanted to export individuals bands. So, by using your code and a small modification of it:

```
// Project the image to Mollweide.
var wkt = ' \
  PROJCS["World_Mollweide", \
    GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984", \
      DATUM["WGS_1984", \
        SPHEROID["WGS_1984",6378137,298.257223563]], \
      PRIMEM["Greenwich",0], \
      UNIT["Degree",0.017453292519943295]], \
    PROJECTION["Mollweide"], \
    PARAMETER["False_Easting",0], \
    PARAMETER["False_Northing",0], \
    PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",0], \
    UNIT["Meter",1], \
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","54009"]]';

var proj_mollweide = ee.Projection(wkt);

var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('VITO/PROBAV/C1/S1_TOC_100M')
                  .filter(ee.Filter.date('2018-01-01', '2018-12-31'))
                  .select(['RED', 'NIR', 'SWIR', 'BLUE'])
                  .median()
                  .divide(2000)
                  .reproject({
                    crs: proj_mollweide,
                    scale: 100
                  });
                  
var red = dataset.select('RED')

Export.image.toDrive({
  image: red ,
  description: 'red',
  scale: 100,
  region: table,
  maxPixels: 1e12,
  folder: 'Landsat-5'
});
```

I can simply change the bands in the `var red = dataset.select('RED')` function and export whatever band I want. In any case, I accepted your answer as the correct one because it solved 99.9% of my problem.